# Align numeric values on the decimal point

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

In Excel I want to align the numbers to the last unit and when there are no decimals, I don't want to display any zeros after the decimal point. I want to align the cells as follows:

```
1234      -->    1,234
1234.12   -->    1,234.1200
1234.123  -->    1,234.1230
1234.1234 -->    1,234.1234
12.1      -->       12.1000
123       -->      123
-123,1234 -->     -123.1234
```

I have Excel 2013.

Comment: (1) [Please don’t post text as images.](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408)  Since this question is about formatting, it falls into one of the exceptional cases where it’s acceptable to post images of text data/examples — although you could have done just as well with code block formatting.  But you really should not post an image *of **part of your question.***  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (2) Your question is ambiguous.  You say, “…when there are no decimals, I don't want to display any zeros *after the decimal point*.” (emphasis added), but your examples for 123 and 1234 indicate that you don’t even want to display the decimal point.  Which is it? (3) How do you want 0.12 to be displayed?  How about 0? (4) You seem to have a typo: the last number in the left column has a comma where it should have a period.

Comment: You are asking for a mixed format for each cell then. You don't want decimals on whole numbers. That said. You are asking for a program, not a formatting design that will auto-format on a new entry. You have to manually do this. Yes indeed a programmer could pull this off in visual basic. This is a specific program and so there wouldn't be a remedy available for download. I've never submitted a work order request, but perhaps you could find a local programmer in your area.

Answer (score 5):

I can’t figure out how to do this in one simple format. 
Here is a two-step solution:

1. Give the cells a custom format of `#,##0.0000`. 
   Alternatively, just format them as Numbers with 4 decimal places
   and check (✓) the “Use 1000 Separator (,)” checkbox:

   [image: "Format Cells" dialog]

   This will cause numbers to be displayed as follows:

   ```
   1234      →  1,234.0000
   1234.12   →  1,234.1200
   0         →      0.0000
   0.12      →      0.1200
   -123.1234 →   -123.1234
   ```
2. Then, apply Conditional Formatting to the cell(s). 
   Letting `Q42` represent the designation of the top-left cell in the range,

   - Select “Use a formula to determine which cells to format”.
   - Under “Format values where this formula is true:”, enter `=INT(Q42)=Q42`. 
     This is true for numbers that are integers; i.e., where there are no decimals.
   - Click on “Format…” and enter a Custom format of `#,##0_._0_0_0_0`. 
     This will cause integers to be displayed as integers
     (with no decimal point or decimal digits),
     but followed with blank space equal to the width of `.0000`, for alignment. 
     (In an Excel format, `_X`, where *`X`* is any character,
     displays as a space with the same width as *`X`*,
     so `_._0_0_0_0` is a space as wide as `.0000`.) 
     And, of course, numbers
     whose absolute value is larger than 999 are displayed
     with commas as thousands separators.
3. Of course, Excel right-justifies numbers by default. 
   As long as you don’t change that,
   Excel will automatically provide enough whitespace to the left of the number
   to get the one’s digits of all the numbers to line up.

The below screenshot demonstrates this answer. 
The first column shows the numbers from your question (and a few others)
unformatted (i.e., in “General” format). 
The second column shows the same numbers, formatted as described above.

[image: demonstration spreadsheet]

Comment: Very interesting formatting... Dear @Scott , may I know the your reference to this `_._0_0_0_` thing.. ? I couldn't seem to find it in the excel help files..

Comment: Well, I can’t tell you where I learned it originally; it was not new to me when I wrote the above (two years ago). But a [Google search for “excel custom formatting”](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+custom+formatting) (and a bit of browsing) yielded four sources: (1) [Review guidelines for customizing a number format - Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Click on “Guidelines for including text and adding spacing” to expand it, scroll down past the table, and see the **Add spaces** paragraph: “To create a space that is the width of a character in a number format, include an underscore character (\_), followed by the character that you want to use.”   (See also [Number format codes - Excel for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68).)   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) [The Definitive Guide to Custom Number Formats in Excel](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel#Underscore-).  (3) [Custom Excel number format](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format#formatting-tips-and-guidelines).  (4) [Custom Number Format in Excel](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/custom-number-format.html#colors): «To add a space, use the underscore "\_" followed by a character. The length of the space will be the length of this character.», oddly hidden under the “Colors” heading.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scott !! Really appreciate your time for digging this.. (I couldn't even figure out the right search keyword to start with.. ) || office.com documentation is there.. but exceltactics explained it much clearer/better than excel OEM.   "(-_-)    ||  I'll cite here the next time I use one. Thanks again.. for guiding me on how to Ctrl+F it. ( :

Comment: You’re welcome.   ([The standard way to say ‘‘thank you’’ for an answer](/help/someone-answers) is to up vote it.)

Comment: I'd rather buy you a coffee.. :Þ

Comment: Well, that might be nice, too.  But a little awkward, since we’re both here anonymously — we could be on different continents, for all I know.  But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the cells that contain the numbers (or the entire column).
2. On the `Home` tab Click `Format` and choose `Format Cells`.
3. In the `Format Cells` dialog switch to the `Number` tab.
4. In the Category list on the left, choose `Custom`.
5. In the `Type` textbox enter `??,???.????`. If your numbers have more than 5 numbers on the left of the decimal period or more than 4 numbers on the right, use more question mark characters.

[image]

Comment: I have Excel 2013, and this doesn’t work for me.  1234 is displayed as `1,234.` (with a **`.`** that the user apparently doesn’t want), 1234.12 is displayed as `1,234.12` (*without* the last two zeroes), and −123 is displayed as `-   123` (with three spaces between the **`-`** and the number).