# How can I center a column in Excel, have the decimal points aligned, and show only the necessary decimal places for each number?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I center a column in Excel, have the decimal points aligned, and show only the necessary decimal places (i.e. not use unnecessary zeros to the right of the decimal point) for each number?
Example of desired output:

```
|      0.12    |
|  1,122       |
|    -12.2835  |
|      0.6667  |
```

In @Scott´s words, when I say “center a column”, I mean the following: “Look at all the numbers in the column.  Find the one with the most characters to the left of the decimal point, and find the one with the most characters to the right of the decimal point. Then adjust the cell margins throughout the column so that those two values are equally far from the corresponding cell border.”

I do not need that the centering adjusts automatically to changes in the maximum number of digit to the right of the left of the decimal point. I can do this manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, align all cells to the right.

You will have to use two different custom formatting: one for decimal numbers and another for integers.

For decimals, use the following custom formating:

```
# ##0.0?????;−# ##0.0?????
```

For integers, use the following custom formatting:

```
# ##0_._0_0_0_0_0_0;−# ##0_._0_0_0_0_0_0
```

`_0` represent a space of a width of `0`.

A space to the left of `##0` indicates the thousand separator selected in your system.

I used a real minus sign (−) instead of a hyphen (-) to improve the typographical output.

The rationale for aligning cells to the right is not to use `?` signs to the left, which would cause spaces between the minus sign and the numerals (except in the figures with the highest amount of digits to the left of the decimal point).

Use as many `?` signs for decimals so as to center the numbers approximately, and the same number of `_0` spaces for integers. This procedure achieves a finer approximation than indenting from the Alignment dialogue window. As @Scott says, "you have to enter your data, and then manually edit the custom format, guesstimating how many question marks you need, visually inspecting the result to see whether it is centered, and then iterate until you get it right".  The above custom formatting fits the example of the question.

Comment: (1) I believe that this is a bad answer.  You nonchalantly say “Use as many ? signs to center the number approximately.”  This is a grammatically broken sentence, although I suppose it’s moderately comprehensible.  But it obscures the fact that you have to enter your data, and then manually edit the custom format, guesstimating how many question marks you need, *visually* inspecting the result to see whether it is centered — and you never defined what you mean by “center a column” — and then iterate until you get it right.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And then do it again when you add a number to the column that’s bigger than what was there before.  I would say that it’s highly unlikely that the OP would find this answer acceptable, but you’ve disproved that.  (2) I consider your third paragraph (“If you do not want to center the numbers in the column …”) to be borderline deceptive.  It tries to affirm that your first two paragraphs are centering the data, when they are not — they are, as you admit, right-justifying the data, and then offsetting it from the right.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) You have spaces in your format, which will, for example, display 65535 as “65  535”, with a space between the thousands’ digit and the hundreds’ digit. The question doesn’t call for this, so somebody who has the problem that your question describes might be really surprised (and not in a good way) about that behavior of your answer. Also, (3a) it displays a space between the minus sign and the number for values strictly between 0 and −1000, and (3b) it displays 4294967296 as “4294967  296”, with a space between the thousands’ digit and the hundreds’ digit, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  but nowhere else. Do you consider that to be acceptable? I expect that most people wouldn’t. ***You*** might know that you will never have a value with a magnitude ≥1000000, but you didn’t specify that in the question. So you have given us the solution to your personal problem, without worrying about whether it will really be useful to other people, or documenting its shortcomings.

Comment: @Scott Custom formatting # ##0 generates thousand separators **every** three digits for integers. If your thousand separator is a comma, you will get 1,000,000,000 (and **not** 1000000,000) for a thousand millions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have columns that end up at whatever width is needed, be it narrow or wide, either one (not just wide but constrained to be more than some minimum width), then it can be done pretty easily.

First, use the following format, editing, as described in a bit, for the maximum decimal places in the column. The format uses `?` characters for the decimal places which creates an equivalent to Word's decimal tab. That way the values line up as you show in your example:

**#,##0.??????**

(You show a decimal only value with a single leading zero, and another value with a comma for its thousands separator so the "#,##0." portion.)

This achieves the lining up of decimal points you desire AND keeps those trailing zeros from having to exist.

Next is achieving the full flower of the "gestalt" of "left-of" and "right-of" the decimal point conditions. In most cases, these would come from two different values, one would think, and those might be widely separated and hard to work the magic with using direct observation as you adjust margins. So let Excel do it for you.

Use the column width adjusting technique where you usually first select (highlight) the column (not necessary, but it concentrates the mind), then move the mouse pointer to the column label area and ease it over to the divider between the column label and the next column label to its right until the pointer changes dramatically, and then double click to tell Excel to set the column width to the narrowest it can be to accommodate the values in the column... **AND** the formatting.

Now the white space on each side of the values that constrain things will be the same. That may not "shine brightly" if you have 6,000 entries and the two cells that constrain things are 4,206 rows apart, but it will be what you are asking for. And readily apparent if the list is small.

Further, if you wish to increase white space and maintain the equal amount on either side, just add space characters to BOTH sides of your custom format. I'll show them using the `\` character for clarity (and set it off with `""` so the trailing one is apparent), but it would not be needed for the spacebar whitespace. All the options other than whitespace characters would need it though:

**"\ #,##0.??????\ "**

Now, how do you determine which cells constrain you? I'd use a simple brute force technique in an array formula ("CSE" so you get the {}'s). The difficulty here is the `bit math` that Excel uses. For instance, to get the decimal portion (which is all I'll address here because once you have one side, subtracting that amount (plus 1 for the decimal point's place) from the total length gives you the other — BUT you never need to know it, so...) one might take each value and subtract its `TRUNC(A1,0)` (truncated to "0" decimal places) value. But... once you do that math operation, a "clean" "0.653" might become "0.652222222222973" to Excel and with the decimal point and the way binary math creates decimals, you might get a length of 17 instead of 3. But it handles text strings flawlessly as the math it does with its source material generates lengths that are spot on (to the unaided eye which is all that matters here).

So, something like the following formula (checking column A):

```
{=IFERROR(LEN(MAX(VALUE(RIGHT(A1:A5,LEN(A1:A5)-FIND(".",TEXT(A1:A5,"@")))))),0)}
```

I believe the ranges must be cell: cell not A:A as each of the functions generates an error when A:A is used in any of them. Also, an integer will generate an error hence wrapping the whole thing in `IFERROR()` to return a `0` as a result if they are all integers.

Basically, it makes the value `TEXT`, finds the decimal point (you COULD just trap the error here, but the above is simpler and not problem causing) and subtracts its location from the overall length to tell `RIGHT()` how many characters to extract to give you the precise decimal portion. `VALUE()` returns them to being numbers so `MAX()` can evaluate them all (it cannot evaluate text), and finally, `LEN()` tells you the length of the longest decimal portion. So you need not examine every cell or risk being wrong:  the simple formula fills you in.

Format the column to have that many `?'s` in its format and you now have everything set for the column's width setting (as above).

All done.

Except for one annoying thing, right? That decimal point for integers...

I've never seen a solution for that using the regular custom formatting. But someone worked around it. Do your regular formatting (like above, or however, in other situations), THEN apply a `Conditional Format` that tests a value for being an integer and formats it to not have the decimal point. Sadly... that won't work for this overall situation as the formatting then has no way for it to line up on the "decimal tab". You COULD experiment with adding white space to the end of the format to push integers over to just about the right spot. It was quick and almost perfect with Comic Sans MS, 11 pt. Use other white space characters to get it perfect. After all, you aren't changing the font so learn it once, apply it easily forever, right?

But it is not a perfectly natural solution. But awfully darn close (unnoticeable to the masses who position pictures and such with a mouse rather than with numbers) and with a mix of two whitespace characters rather than just space characters, I believe it would satisfy even me.

I think I touched on everything you asked for. Long to describe, very quick and easy to implement and use. Just enter things, get the number of decimal places and edit the column format, auto-adjust the width, add space characters to both sides if the whitespace isn't enough, and boom, done.

Comment: “someone worked around it” — I guess [you mean me](https://superuser.com/q/1140321/150988#1141347). But — “that won't work … as the formatting then has no way for it to line up on the "decimal tab".” What do you mean? (Did you see [my solution](https://superuser.com/q/1140321/150988#1141347)?)